# Django Rest Framework | TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict([('name', 'string')])

Tags: python, django, typeerror, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to update a ManyToManyField in a UserProfile, which is part of my custom User model in my Django REST API. However, I get this error:
`TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict([('name', 'string')])`

Since I'm doing this in my `update()` method in my UserSerializer, I already have an instance created.

**account/serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'tokens', 'userprofile']
        # Read-only b/c doesn't need any validating parameters
        read_only_fields = ['tokens']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Perform an update on User"""
        # Remove password field b/c we don't want to iterate over it in the
        # validated_data dictionary. Django will salt/hash it.
        validated_data.pop('password', None)
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile', {})
        skills = profile_data.pop('skills', [])

        for (key, value) in validated_data.items():
            # Set remaining keys in the user
            setattr(instance, key, value)

        instance.save()

        for (key, value) in profile_data.items():
            setattr(instance.userprofile, key, value)

        for skill in skills:
            instance.userprofile.skills.add(skill)

        instance.userprofile.save()

        return instance
```

The error occurs when I call `add()` for updating the user's skills. The model and serializer for Skill are defined below:

**user_profile/models.py**

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**user_profile/serializers.py**

```
class SkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Skill
        fields = '__all__'
```

My first guess is that the `skill` variable in the for-loop just takes an OrderedDict from the PUT request, but I have to pass that data into a Skills instance. Is this correct? How can I change this line to fix this error?

Comment: Can you show `UserProfileSerializer` and your request data?